# How to show that $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous?

Tags: analysis, proof-verification

Show that the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x)=|x|$ is continuous. I only know how to prove the function is continuous at some point. How to prove this one? To prove that it is continuous at all $x_0$?

Comment: Is it clear for you that $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$ are continuous $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes but how to prove it?

Comment: "I only know how to prove the function is continuous at some point": what "some point" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That a function is continuous simply means that it is continuous at every point of its domain.

A trivial $\epsilon,\delta$-proof goes as follows.

Let $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\delta = \epsilon > 0$. Then for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < |x-x_0| < \delta$, we trivially have $||x|-|x_0|| \leq |x-x_0| < \epsilon$ by our choice of $\delta = \epsilon$.

The inequality $||x|-|x_0||\leq|x-x_0|$ is simply the reverse triangle inequality.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, then the inequality $||x|-|y||\leq |x-y|$ is the best place to start.

Answer (score 1):

For all the $x_0 > 0$  you have in a neighbourhood of $x_0$ that $|x|=x$ and you know $f(x)=x$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$. The same goes for $x_0<0$. Then you only have to prove the continuity in $0$. Considering that:

-$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} |x|=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} -x=0$

-$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} |x|=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} x=0$

you can conclude that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} |x|=0 $$

therefore the function is continuous in $0$.

EDIT to prove that a function is continuous you just have to prove that it is continuous in every point (in fact, that's the definition)